# Jquery Full Calendar plugin not rendering first tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, fullcalendar

I have a couple of FullCalendar instances each in its own Tab.
At first when I switched tabs, the calendars did not display, so I added this part to render the calendars once you click on a tab

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var redrawcal = $(this).attr('href');
    redrawcal = redrawcal.substring(1,redrawcal.length);
    $('#calendar_'+redrawcal).fullCalendar('render');
    $('.fc-today').removeClass('fc-today');
});
```

This works perfectly for each tab after the first, however, the first Tab's calendar's event times are incorrect.

As shown in the image below, the second tab's events are correct:
[image]

---

But The first tab does not rerender the events correct, the initial placement and the placement if you switch tabs are exactly the same, as seen in the image below:

[image]

---

I have the following code that's suppose to render the calendar after it has been created at first:

```
$(function(){
    //first tab's calander is not rendering correctly, this will make it show correct from the start
    <?php $branch = $branches[0]; ?>
    <?php $branch_studio_id = str_replace(" ", "_", $branch['branch_studio_name']); ?>
    <?php $branch_studio_id = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $branch_studio_id); ?>

    $('#calendar_<?= $branch_studio_id; ?>').fullCalendar('render');
});
```

For this example, the calendar's id is `calendar_Centurion`, the PHP simply removes spaces and special characters

I have also tried this:

```
$('#calendar_<?= $branch_studio_id; ?>').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

But I still have the same results.
The two events in the two calendars have exactly the same times on the same day, and all information is the same

If there is only one Tab, it is broken without an extra tab to rerender the calendar.

I have basically tries everything that I could find and that I could think of that might help but with no positive results.

Unfortunately I cannot create a fiddle of this as it would take quite long to do so and the actual code/project is not open to the public as of yet.

I do hope this can be easily solved.

Thanx in advance!

---

**UPDATE**
Below is the HTML and JS code for my calendars

```
<?php $branch_studio_id = str_replace(" ", "_", trim($branch['branch_studio_name'])); ?>
<?php $branch_studio_id = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $branch_studio_id); ?>

<div class="tab-pane <?=($x == 1) ? 'active' : '' ?>" id="<?=$branch_studio_id ?>">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div id="calendar_<?= $branch_studio_id ?>"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="h4 text-light">Classes not on timetable</p>
            <hr />
            <div id='external-events_<?=$branch_studio_id ?>'>
                <?php foreach ($classes_notimetable as $class) :?>
                    <?php if ($class['studio_id'] == $branch['studio_id']) : ?>
                        <div class="external-event label label-success" data-event-class="fc-event-success" data-class-id="<?=$class['id']?>"><?=$class['class_name'] ?></div>
                    <?php endif;?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {

        'use strict';

        var initCalendarDragNDrop<?=$x;?> = function() {
            $('#external-events_<?=$branch_studio_id ?> div.external-event').each(function() {
                // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
                // it doesn't need to have a start or end
                var eventObject<?=$x;?> = {
                    title : $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                };
                // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
                $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject<?=$x;?>);
                // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                $(this).draggable({
                    zIndex : 999,
                    revert : true,
                    revertDuration:0
                });
            });
        };

        var initCalendar<?=$x;?> = function() {
            var $calendar<?=$x;?> = $('#calendar_<?=$branch_studio_id ?>');
            var date = new Date();
            var daynum = date.getDay();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $calendar<?=$x;?>.fullCalendar({
                header: {left:   '', center: '', right:  ''},
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                slotDuration: '00:10:00',
                snapDuration: '00:05:00',
                firstDay : 1,
                columnFormat: 'ddd',
                minTime:'<?= (isset($school_custom['school_from_hour'])) ? $school_custom['school_from_hour'] : '08'; ?>:<?= (isset($school_custom['school_from_minutes'])) ? $school_custom['school_from_minutes'] : '00'; ?>',
                maxTime: '<?= (isset($school_custom['school_to_hour'])) ? $school_custom['school_to_hour'] : '21'; ?>:<?= (isset($school_custom['school_to_minutes'])) ? $school_custom['school_to_minutes'] : '00'; ?>',
                allDaySlot: false,
                defaultTimedEventDuration: '01:00:00',
                forceEventDuration:true,
                editable : true,
                eventDrop: function(event) {
                        var eventid = event.id; 
                        var eventday = (event.start._d).getDay();
                        var eventstarthour = (event.start._d).getHours()-2;
                        var eventstartminute = (event.start._d).getMinutes();
                        var eventendhour = (event.end._d).getHours()-2;
                        var eventendminute = (event.end._d).getMinutes();
                        $('').postJsonCheck('classes/update_class_times', {event_id: eventid, event_day:eventday, event_starthour:eventstarthour,event_startminute:eventstartminute,event_endhour:eventendhour,event_endminute:eventendminute}, function(data){

                        });                                     
                    },
                droppable : true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
                drop : function(date) {// this function is called when something is dropped
                    var $externalEvent = $(this);

                    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                    var originalEventObject = $externalEvent.data('eventObject');

                    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                    // assign it the date that was reported
                    copiedEventObject.start = date;
                    //copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                    copiedEventObject.className = $externalEvent.attr('data-event-class');

                    var classid = parseInt($(this).attr('data-class-id'));  
                    copiedEventObject.id = classid;

                    // render the event on the calendar
                    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                    $('#calendar_<?=$branch_studio_id ?>').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                    //Update DB
                        var eventday = (copiedEventObject.start._d).getDay();
                        var eventstarthour = (copiedEventObject.start._d).getHours()-2;
                        var eventstartminute = (copiedEventObject.start._d).getMinutes();
                        var eventendhour = (copiedEventObject.start._d).getHours()-1;
                        var eventendminute = (copiedEventObject.start._d).getMinutes();
                        $('').postJsonCheck('classes/add_class_timetable', {class_id: classid, event_day:eventday, event_starthour:eventstarthour,event_startminute:eventstartminute,event_endhour:eventendhour,event_endminute:eventendminute}, function(data){

                        }); 

                    //remove the event from the not on timbetable list
                    $(this).remove();

                },
                eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                    var classid = event.id; 
                    var eventendhour = (event.end._d).getHours()-2;
                    var eventendminute = (event.end._d).getMinutes();
                    $('').postJsonCheck('classes/update_class_duration', {class_id: classid, event_endhour:eventendhour,event_endminute:eventendminute}, function(data){

                    }); 

                },
                events : [<?php $z = 0;?>
                    <?php foreach ($classes as $class): ?>
                        <?php $z++;?>
                        <?php if ($class['studio_id'] == $branch['studio_id']) : ?>
                            {
                                id: <?=$class["day_id"]?>,
                                title: '<?=$class["class_name"]?>',
                                start: new Date(y, m, d-(daynum-<?=$class["day"]?>), '<?=$class["start_hour"]?>', '<?=$class["start_minute"]?>'),
                                end: new Date(y, m, d-(daynum-<?=$class["day"]?>), '<?=$class["end_hour"]?>', '<?=$class["end_minute"]?>')
                            }
                        <?php if ($z < count($classes))echo ","?>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>]
                });
            };

            $(function() {
                initCalendar<?=$x;?>();
                initCalendarDragNDrop<?=$x;?>();
            });

        }).apply($(this), [jQuery]);

</script>
```

*Please note that there is a php foreach loop outside of the above code, so this code gets duplicated for each calendar, each with a unique `$branch_studio_id` used in the calendar's ID

Comment: `.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');` there's no such method. "refetchEvents" might be what you're looking for? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/ . It shouldn't be necessary though to solve your problem. Also, do both calendars have the exact same options declared, as well as the exact same events? Can you a show a sample of the offending event data, and your calendar setup please? Doesn't need to be a working fiddle, just the code. And if you have any custom CSS which impacts on the calendar (from the screenshot it looks like you might) then show that too.

Comment: It occurs to me that you should first remove the custom CSS and re-test, and see if the issue persists.

Comment: The calendars have the exact same options defined when they are initializing, but the event will not necessarily be the same, I just added two events on the same time slot to use in the example. The only Custom CSS that I have on the page is to make the top header thinner, but removed that and still does the same. I added the code for my calendars in the question